# Actionbar Sherlock Not Found in Test Build Script

Tags: android, spock, robospock

I have 2 gradle.build scripts, one for my app and one for my test. The app has a dependency on actionbarsherlock as follows:

```
dependencies {

    compile project(':shared-jars')

    compile ('com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
}
```

and `assembleRelease` works correctly.

However when doing a build, the test build doesn't compile because it can't find actionbarsherlock.  For example:

```
14:27:52.847 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.jdk6.Jdk6JavaCompiler] Compiling with JDK Java compiler API.
14:27:54.240 [ERROR] [system.err] /Users/bradrhoads/Documents/src/estante/src/android/src/main/java/org/maf/estante/Discover.java:13: package com.actionbarsherlock.app does not exist
```

I've tried adding the same compile dependency in the test build as well as trying to depend on the app's transitive dependencies. But in eather case I get the not found error. Here's the entire test build script:

```
def props = new Properties()
file("../local.properties").withInputStream {
    stream -> props.load(stream)
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url new File(props['sdk.dir'] + "/extras/android/m2repository/").toURI()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'groovy'


dependencies {
    compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:1.8.6"
    compile 'org.robospock:robospock:0.4.4'

    compile 'cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1'

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:4.0.1'


    //compile fileTree(dir: ':android:libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(":shared-jars")

    compile ('com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

    compile (project(":estanteApp")) {
        transitive = true
    }


}

sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs = ['../android/src/main/java', '../android/build/source/r/debug']

test {

    systemProperty 'ro.build.date.utc', '1'
    systemProperty 'ro.kernel.qemu', '0'

    beforeTest { descriptor ->
        logger.lifecycle("Running test: " + descriptor)
    }

    testLogging {
        lifecycle {
            exceptionFormat "full"
        }
    }

    workingDir = '../android/src/main'

}


tasks["test"].dependsOn project(":estanteApp").tasks["compileDebugJava"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy plugin doesn't understand the aar dependency. Currently only android* plugins can evaluate such dependencies.

You could try first to assemble the Android project and link to build/exploded-aar/com.actionbarsherlock/actionbarsherlock/4.4.0/classes.jar but I'm not sure how robolectric will act with resources from aar lib.

Comment: Thanks. I'll go back to building ABS from source.